# Update cell in row with current date when there is a change in that row

Tags: google-sheets

I found two scripts. Since they both were an onEdit() function they couldn't work side by side, I tried to merge them.

I am using this sheet for a very basic inventory of things I sell / keep track of what I have sold.

I want two things;
First: I would like the cell in column A to change to the current date whenever I do a change on that row.
Second: If I change the value in column B to "Sold" I want it to be moved to a different sheet (as well as getting a new date due the change).

Column B has the following choices:
-Ja (as in stock)
-Bokad (as in booked)
-Såld (as in sold)

The name of the Sheets are:
-Blocket (inventory)
-Sålda (sold)

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named Blocket
// target sheet of move to named Sålda
// test column with "Såld" is col 2

var s = event.source.getActiveSheet(),
cols = [2], 
colStamp = 1,
ind = cols.indexOf(event.range.columnStart)
if (s.getName() == 'Blocket' || ind == -1) return;
event.range.offset(0, parseInt(colStamp - cols[ind]))
.setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Blocket" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == "Såld") 
{
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sålda");
if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {

targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 20); //inserts 20 rows 
after last used row
}
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row); 
}
}
```

Comment: if the 2 script you found worked, why don't you simply change the name and then create your own `onEdit(event)` function that calls both scripts?

Comment: I could not understand how that worked... Coding is just not my thing I guess :(

Comment: Sadly stackoverflow is not a good ressource to teach you how to code... The script you have here seems okay to me, doesn't it do what you want it to?

Comment: `if (s.getName() == 'Blocket' || ind == -1) return;` this line stops the script if the modification is in the `Blocket` sheet, I don't think that is what you want

Comment: Didnt know where else to turn, script doesnt work at all :)

Comment: try to remove ` if (s.getName() == 'Blocket' || ind == -1) return;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s, targetSheet;
s = e.source.getActiveSheet();

if (s.getName() !== 'Blocket' || e.range.columnStart == 1) return;
s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1)
    .setValue(new Date());

if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value == "Såld") {
    targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sålda");

    if (targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {
        targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 20); //inserts 20 rows 
    }
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
}
}
```

Comment: Oooh, this worked like a charm, thanks mate. Really saved my day! <3